# Sql multiple condition in two tables returning wrong data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySql tables with following schema

```
Courses(CNO:CHAR(10),CName:VARCHAR(50), DeptId:CHAR(3)): Each course is given a
unique ID called CNO
Register(RNO:CHAR(10), CNO:CHAR(10), Year:INTEGER, Sem:INTEGER, Grade:CHAR)
```

Now I have to find all (RNO, Year, Sem) triples such that a student with Roll No. RNO in the semester
defined by Year, Sem has taken/registered for at least three or more distinct courses, each offered by a different department.

My code is following

```
With tmp AS(
    SELECT Register.RNO,Register.CNO,Register.Year,Register.Sem,courses.DeptId, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY DeptId) 
    AS rn 
    from Register 
    inner join courses 
    on courses.CNO=Register.CNO
)
select RNO, Year, Sem
from tmp
where rn=1
GROUP BY RNO,Year,Sem 
having COUNT(CNO)>=3;
```

(I am using **Row_Number** to get apply **Distinct** keyword on one of the column)
However this code is failing in the case where student is registered in more than three courses in two different semester and output is comming out to be 1 row instead of two row. Why it is happening and how to resolve it

Here is the sql code for sample data and schema

```
    CREATE TABLE courses (
    CNO CHAR(10),
    CName VARCHAR(50),
    DeptId CHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (CNO)
);



INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("CS1","database","CSE");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("CS2","deep","CSE");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("CS3","prob","CSE");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("MBA4","consume","IME");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("MBA5","Model","IME");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("MBA7","consume","IME");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("MBA8","Model","IME");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("SOC6","Social","HSS");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("MBA10","consume","IME");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("MBA11","Model","IME");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("SOC12","Social","HSS");
INSERT INTO courses (CNO,CName,DeptId)
VALUES ("SOC9","Social","HSS");

CREATE TABLE Register (
    RNO CHAR(10),
    CNO CHAR(10), 
    Year INTEGER, 
    Sem INTEGER,
    Grade CHAR,
    FOREIGN KEY (CNO) REFERENCES courses(CNO)
);    

INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","CS1",1,1,"B");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","CS2",1,1,"A");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","CS3",1,1,"B");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","MBA4",1,1,"B");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","MBA5",1,1,"A");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","SOC6",1,1,"A");

INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","MBA7",2,2,"B");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","MBA8",2,2,"A");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","SOC9",2,2,"A");

INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","MBA10",3,3,"B");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","MBA11",4,3,"A");
INSERT INTO Register (RNO,CNO,Year,Sem,Grade)
VALUES ("1","SOC12",5,3,"A");
```

Here is a [link to a DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nUoZFAqvdohYSp72fsaAkg/0).

Comment: I added a link to a "DB Fiddle", the one extra step you should have taken. When your query is run, however, it seems to return no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got it right

```
select Register.RNO, Register.Year, Register.Sem 
from Register 
inner join courses on courses.CNO=Register.CNO
group by RNO,Year,Sem 
having COUNT(distinct courses.CNO)>=3 and COUNT(distinct courses.DeptId) >=3;
```